# When using a button in tkinter/python, is there a way to change the button text based on a dictionary?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a small program that quizzes people and reuses the same 4 radio buttons. I need each question to represent a new answer choice for each new question.

The simplified dictionary I need to access is as follows:

```
{"1":  {"text": "America is the place where ______________ come true.", "answer": "dreams",
        "points": "1", "choices":
                           {"1": "dreams", "2": "wishes", "3": "visions", "4": "fantasies"}},
 "2": {"text":  "Which artist released the album 808s & Heartbreak?", "answer": "kanye", "points":"3", "choices": 
                           {"1": "kanye west", "2": "mike jones", "3": "kodak black", "4": "drake"}}}
```

and the function to return an answer is:

```
def iterate_answer_choices(questions_num=1, answer_num=1):
  global temp_dict

  q_num = str(questions_num)
  a_num = str(answer_num)

  question2 = "2"
  answer3 = "3"
  return(temp_dict[q_num]['choices'][a_num])
```

The button would look as follows:

`temp_a = StringVar()
temp_a.set(iterate_answer_choices(1, 4))
rad_btn2 = Radiobutton(window, value=2, textvariable=temp_a, indicatoron=0)
rad_btn2.pack()`

I am aware I can create a StringVar() to hold the text needed in the button, but that will not change when I need a new variable. I will have at least 10 questions with 4 answers each so that's not viable. 
I have also tried linking textvalue to a lambda function tat returns text, but that didnt work either. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use `.set(...`, read up on [Tkinter.Radiobutton.config-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm#Tkinter.Radiobutton.config-method)

Comment: I am aware, but I still don't see how I can use this to have the buttons update its text without writing the .config every time i need to update a button. I tried updating the textariable using .config but that would still have me referring to a StringVar in order to update. It wont let me refer to a function that auto updates when called

Comment: ***I am aware ... updating the textariable***: So, why do you still want to use it?

Comment: Because i need the text/textvariable (answer choices) to change on the 4 SAME buttons to 4 NEW answer choices when a submit button is pressed. I didn't explain that in my first issue. I'm just so out of it at this point

Comment: ***answer choices***: Yes, but only `.get()`, never `.set(...)`. Be aware, the`textvarable=` is associated with `value=`and not with the `text=` showing.

Comment: I was able to add a formatted string to text= but now i cant't get it to iterate lol

Comment: ***cant't get it to iterate***: To iterate your questions `dict`, is independent from `.configure(text=`. Try to iterate using the`dict` **key** `{"1": ...`. It would be simpler to iterate if the **key** is of type `int` instead of `str`.